# Scroll LongListSelector when new item added

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, longlistselector

I have a chat application that shows messages in a `LongListSelector` and adds new ones with the statement `ObservableCollection.Insert(0, message)`.

My issue is that when a new message is added, the LongListSelector doesn't scroll down to the new message.

The best solution in my opinion would be to automatically scroll to new messages if the LongListSelector is currently scrolled to the top, but I cannot find a method to detect current scrolling position (I see only `LongListSelector.ScrollTo()`, which isn't helpful).

How can I automatically scroll to new messages when the LongListSelector is currently scrolled to the top?

Comment: Could you explain why ScrollTo is not helpful? If you provide the object "message" which you inserted into your collection, it will scroll to it. That's exactly what you wanted - right?

Comment: @eX0du5, Yes, that is what i want. But I need to enable autoscrolling only if the LongListSelector is currently scrolled to the top.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to find current scroll position than you need to get the scrollbar inside longlistselector using VisualTreeHelper.

The sample function:

```
public static class VisualChildExtractHelper
{

  public static T FindChildOfType<T>(DependencyObject root) where T : class
  {
    var queue = new Queue<DependencyObject>();
    queue.Enqueue(root);

    while (queue.Count > 0)
    {
        DependencyObject current = queue.Dequeue();
        for (int i = VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(current) - 1; 0 <= i; i--)
        {
            var child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(current, i);
            var typedChild = child as T;
            if (typedChild != null)
            {
                return typedChild;
            }
            queue.Enqueue(child);
        }
    }
    return null;
  }
}
```

usage:

```
ScrollBar LongListSelectorScrollBar = VisualChildExtractHelper.FindChildOfType<ScrollBar>(yourLongListSelectorName);
```

After that you can access ScrollBar Value (or ValueChanged event) and check if it equals 0 (that means that longlistselector is scrolled to the top) or other condition. If it is you can ScrollTo method of LongListSelector to bring element into view.

Comment: Thank you for answer! But `VisualChildExtractHelper.FindChildOfType<ScrollViewer>(yourLongListSelectorName)` always returns null. Where is could be the problem?

Comment: In the FindChildOfType method child!=null, but typedChild always is null. As I see the problem is here. How to fix it?

Comment: Sorry, it seems, that LongListSelector doesn't contain scrollviewer. ScrollViewer is inside Listbox. However there is ScrollBar inside LongListSelector and its Value Property and ValueChanged event. See my updated answer.